# Almost there?? Help with inequality.(updated)

Tags: inequality

I was recently doing a combinatorics problem from MMO given in book Arthur Engel. I might have solved it (though unlikely) as I arrived at following inequality:-

Both $x$ and $y$ are positive. the first term is not in the pattern, while rest are.

$($$\frac{(x^3+y^3)}{(x+y)^3}$$)$ + $($$\frac{(x^4+y^4+x^3y+y^3x+x^2y^2)}{(x+y)^4}$ + $\frac{(x^5+y^5+x^4y+y^4x+x^3y^2+x^2y^3)}{(x+y)^5}$ ....$)$  $<1$ ?

I don't know if it is true (not good with inequalities). Please verify it.
Any help is appreciated :)

I can post the question if you want to give it a try but please don't tell the solution here.

[image]

My method:
$(1)$ All triangles are similar and each triangle has unique a unique area. Two triangles are congruent iff their areas are equal. Then, I constructed an ''area-based representation''

$(2)$ If the bigger RAT(Right angled triangle) into area $x$ and $y$, Then when we divide the RAT with area $x$ we end up with triangles of areas: $x^2/(x+y)$ and $xy/(x+y)$. So if we just keep dividing the RAT (not caring about congruency at this point)  We end up with the nth row of pascals triangle/$(x+y)^{(n-2)}$.

```
                  1(x+y)
               1(x)  1(y)
         1(x^2/(x+y)) 2(xy/(x+y)) 1(y^2/(x+y))
 1(x^3/(x+y)^2) 3(x^2y/(x+y)^2)  3(xy^2/(x+y)^2) 1(y^3/(x+y)^2)
```

$(3)$ If we keep the first triangle unchanged, then divide the second triangle into $x$ and $y$, then divide the third into $x^2/(x+y)$,$y^2/(x+y)$,$xy/(x+y)$,$x^2y/(x+y)^2$,$xy^2/(x+y)^2$, then the fourth triangle must be
$($$\frac{(x^3+y^3)}{(x+y)^2}$$)$ + $($$\frac{(x^4+y^4+x^3y+y^3x+x^2y^2)}{(x+y)^3}$ + $\frac{(x^5+y^5+x^4y+y^4x+x^3y^2+x^2y^3)}{(x+y)^4}$ ....$)$
which I wanted to show is less than $x+y$

$Attempt(promising?)$

I noticed that in case of maximum area we can't get $(x^4,y^4,x^5,y^5...)$ , then I mordified the inequality but was only able to give the required proof for $0.276 < x <  0.723 $

Reason:  Notice that when we are dividing one single triangle we can get many terms but from the each of the sets $S_x$ and $S_y$ we can only get one term from each ( so in total $2$ distinct terms and think about this yourself )

$S_x = (1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4...) $

$S_y = (1,y,y^2,y^3,y^4...) $

And since there are four triangles we can get (**in max area case**) ${1,x,y,x^2,y^2,x^3,y^3}$

Comment: The pattern is unclear as the first numerator does not have terms like $x^2y, xy^2$. Further taking $y\to 0^+$, the LHS blows up so fast it's unlikely to hold true.

Comment: yes the first numerator is not supposed to have these terms, only the numerator after that are in a pattern

Comment: @Macavity does it hold true for `x,y`>1? maybe I can find a way from there.

Comment: Well, really it's the ratio $x/y$ that matters, as the terms are homogeneous, and that can get really large even if both are above $1$.

Comment: @Macavity Can you submit that as an answer, I don't get it

Comment: Why don't you put up the actual combinatorial problem and how you got this inequality from there? The current question seems a bit whimsical to attempt seriously. The observation i made is more of a comment than a formal answer.

Comment: I will post that

Comment: @Macavity I will post my method later, currently having a class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123976/discussion-between-saket-kumar-and-macavity).

Comment: The specific problem you refer to in Arthur Engels book seems to be for finding an invariant (which is clearly possible). How did you end up with the inequality you mention  from that problem? Perhaps there was some interim step which was wrong.

Comment: Like Macavity expressed, you likely got the invariant step wrong. Can you write it up? You should end up with showing that $ \sum 1 / 2^n 2^m  = 4$, so any finite sum is less than 4.

Comment: @Macavity  I have posted my method

Comment: @Calivinl  I have posted my method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your LHS is correct, you can assume from homogeneity and symmetry, WLOG let $t= x/y > 1$:
$$\frac{x^3+y^3}{(x+y)^3}+\sum_{n=5}^\infty \frac{\sum_{k=0}^n x^{n-k}y^k}{(x+y)^n}  = \frac{t^3+1}{(t+1)^3}+ \sum_{n=5}^\infty \frac{\sum_{k=0}^nt^k}{(t+1)^n} = f(t)$$
Then (*using GP formula, you can / should do the working yourself*)
$$f(t)=\frac{t^2-t+1}{(t+1)^2}+\frac1{t-1}\sum_{n=5}^\infty\left( t\cdot\left(\frac{t}{t+1}\right)^n-\frac1{(t+1)^n}\right) \\= \frac{t^6+2t^5+2t^4+t^3+2t^2+2t+1}{t(t+1)^4}$$

It is clear that $f(t)$ increases without bound (as numerator is a higher degree polynomial), and in fact even$f(2)= \dfrac{181}{162}>1$.

Comment: thanks :) , PS I am not familiar with GP and all that

Comment: GP : Geometric Progression is usually covered earlier than attempting MMOs...

Comment: I don't go to any tutor  for that specific purpuse

Comment: live in india, Currently we don't learn Gp by class 11

Comment: Do you want to see my method or should I delete the post?

Answer (score 1):

(This is more of a comment regarding OP's approach to the original question. It's not a complete solution.)

With regards to your method, you're on the right track.

- Note that $ x + y = 1$, so you could get rid of that.
- Note that the triangles are split up into areas of size $ x^a y^b$.
- For $ (x, y) \neq (1/2, 1/2)$, 2 triangles are congruent iff $ a_1 = a_2, b_1 = b_2$.

  - Hence, if we have distinct triangles, then their areas will be a subset of $ 1, x, y, x^2, xy, y^2, x^3, x^2y , xy^2, y^3, ... $
  - Notice that this  is different from your value.
- For $ (x, y) = (1/2, 1/2)$, w triangles are congruent iff $a_1 + b_1 = a_2 + b_2$.

  - (For now, I will ignore this case and leave it to you).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124140/discussion-on-answer-by-calvin-lin-almost-there-help-with-inequality).

Comment: @Calvinl sorry for bogus proof. Just noticed that in case of maximum area we can't get $x^4$,$y^4$,$x^5$,$y^5$.... but that still doesn't complete the proof as I get an inequality that says that we are bound to get congruent triangles for $0.276<x<0.723$

Comment: @saketkumar I'm not sure what you mean. It's possible to get those triangles still. In the "proper approach", essentially the only substitution is $ x = y = 1/2$, which has a value of 4 when we have infinitely many pieces, hence a contradiction.

Comment: @Calvinl I will post the complete solution in some time

Comment: @Calvinl here is a hint as to why we can't get all of them : Notice that all of them lie on the edge of the pascal triangle made earlier

Comment: @saketkumar Right, we can get 4 triangles of the form $x^n$, but there's no restriction on which ones. Yes, it makes sense that we want to keep the large ones, but that might have implications elsewhere. Also, like you pointed out, your approach doesn't work for all $x$.

Comment: @CalvinLin I don't think it has any such implications as if we chose triangles other than the set mention earlier we would be just subtraction more from the LHS of inequality ,making it easier to proof.

Comment: @Calvinl I am not  sure what you mean to say when $x=y=0.5$ . Though it does give a contradiction, it is for the special case of isosceles right angled triangle ,in which case the number of congruent triangles is clearly more that those in case of non-isosceles triangles. I don't know how you were able to generalize from this specific case

Comment: @saketkumar I am in agreement. As I've mentioned, ignore the CASE of $ x = y = 0.5$. HOWEVER, the proof for other $x, y$ values, boils down to $ 1 + x + y + x^2 + xy + y^2 + \ldots = 4 $ FOR the specific values of $ x = y = 0.5$. In particular, there's a "weight change" involved (whether explicitly stated or implicitly done).

Comment: @CalvinLin Can you please tell me more about this '' weight change'' maybe that's what I am missing?

Comment: @saketkumar Read the solution in Arthur Engel.

Comment: @CalvinLin I was able to solve the kontsevich problem mention and notice the similarity but I doubt the proof as it assigns equal weight to triangles of unequal areas

Comment: @saketkumar That's what I meant by "weight change".  A $ x^n y^m $ triangle is split into a $x^{n+1} y^m$ and $x^ny^{m+1}$ triangle. We can use any weight system for the mono variance as long as $ f( x^n y^m ) = f ( x^{n+1} y^m ) + f(x^ny^{m+1}) $. While the "natural choice" is $f( x^n y^m) = x^n y^m $, that doesn't easily yield the desired conclusion. We could use $f (x^n y^m) = 1/2^{n+m} $ and reach the conclusion. (Another system we could use is $ f( x^n y^m ) = 1 $ if $ n \geq m$, else 0. Clearly, this doesn't give us the desired conclusion either. )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124265/discussion-between-saket-kumar-and-calvin-lin).

Comment: @CalvinLin Why does this condition : $f(x^ny^m) = f(x^{n+1}y^m) + f(x^ny^{m+1}) $ enable us to choose the weight system of our choice?

Comment: In order to have an invariance, the old weights (LHS) must be equal to the new weights (RHS) every time we split a triangle.

Comment: @CalvinLin I feel a certain kind of guilt after viewing the solution. Is this feeling common or is it just me?

Comment: @saketkumar Nope, it's not just you. I learned a lot from reading solutions, especially when you're just starting to learn about a topic/technique. There's an art to it, where the goal is to figure out why you couldn't come up with the solution. Was it that you didn't know a fact (mono variance principle), didn't make an observation (how to split triangles), couldn't find a constraint (formula weighting has to satisfy), or couldn't see how to use through (finding a weighting that works). Use that to tweak how you approach the next problem in the list.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks :). Here I wasn't able to use the weighing. I knew that weighing as I had earlier solved the kontsevich problem, But I didn't think that we could apply that to this particular situation